How to show custom exception message(RecordsNotFoundException) in laravel 8?
Trying to display custom message for the RecordsNotFoundException, but I am getting '404 | NOT FOUND' instead of 'Record with id :123 not found, please try different Id'
if (empty($data)) throw new RecordsNotFoundException('Record with id :123 no found, please try different Id');



Did you check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#the-exception-handler

@Liju, How did you configure exception handler?Show the code.You should use ModelNotFoundException which is thrown when a record is not found.
